# How serialized a python class in yaml flux

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have this python program:

```
import yaml
import pprint

class DictProductCart(object):

    def __init__(self, dicta, dictb):
        self.dicta = dicta
        self.dictb = dictb

    def __repr__(self):
        result = str()
        chaine=str()
        for clea,valeura in iter(sorted(self.dicta.iteritems())):
            chaine = "%s: %s,\n" % (clea,self.dictb)
            result = result + chaine
        return result

yaml_str= """\
!!python/object:__main__.DictProductCart
dicta: {a: 1, b: 2}
dictb: {i: 10, j: 20}
"""
testdata = yaml.load(yaml_str)
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
pp.pprint(testdata)
```

The result is ok:

```
a: {'i': 10, 'j': 20},
b: {'i': 10, 'j': 20},
```

Now, I make the yaml data in a file:

```
!!python/object:__main__.DictProductCart
dicta: {a: 1, b: 2}
dictb: {i: 10, j: 20}
```

But when I run the program I have this error:

```
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:mod_dictproductcart.DictProductCart'
  in "toto.yaml", line 1, column 1
```

Have you got an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

in python3 use: `for clea,valeura in iter(sorted(self.dicta.items())):` instead

```
for clea,valeura in iter(sorted(self.dicta.iteritems())):
```